# How do I move to different parts of code in this game/story

Tags: python

After the initial question of how much do you take, it works fine. If you type 0 you die, 5 million it says nice take. After it says nice take, it exits the program and forgets the rest of the code.

How do I get python to load the next part of the code and run it.

```
from sys import exit

def bank_vault():
    print "This room is full of money up to 5 million dollars. How much do you take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in choice:
        dead("You are robbing a bank and took nothing... The cops shot you in the face.")
        how_much = int(choice)

    if how_much < 5000000:
        print "Nice take, now you have to escape!"
        escape_route()

def escape_route():
    print "There are cops blocking the front door."
    print "There are cops blocking the back door."
    print "There is no way to get out of there."
    print "You see a small opening on the ceiling."
    print "Type ceiling to go through it."
    print "Or type stay to try your luck."
    escaped_cops = False

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "stay":
            dead("Your bank robbing friends left your stupid ass and the cops shot you in the face. Idiot move dipshit.")

        elif choice == "ceiling" and not escaped_cops:
            print "You escaped! Now wash that money and don't go to prison."
            escaped_cops = True

def dead(why):
    print why, ""
    exit(0)

bank_vault()
```

Comment: Needs reformatting... Also, you seem to be trying to convert your `choice` to an `int` after you've called the `dead` function, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool game. I love games and would like to try to improve your code. Code below works on Python 3. It should work on Python 2:

```
from sys import exit

try: input = raw_input          # To make it work both in Python 2 and 3
except NameError: pass

def bank_vault():
    print("This room is full of money up to 5 million dollars. How much do you take?")

    how_much = int(input("> ")) # Why not eliminate choice variable here?

    if how_much == 0:
        dead("You are robbing a bank and took nothing... The cops shot you in the face.")
    elif how_much < 5000000:    # Changed to else condition
        print("Nice take, now you have to escape!")
    else:                       # Added a check
        dead("There isn't that much!")


def escape_route():
    print("There are cops blocking the front door.")
    print("There are cops blocking the back door.")
    print("There is no way to get out of there.")
    print("You see a small opening on the ceiling.")
    print("Type ceiling to go through it.")
    print("Or type stay to try your luck.")
    escaped_cops = False

    while not escaped_cops:
        choice = input("> ")

        if choice == "stay":
            dead("Your bank robbing friends left your stupid ass and the cops shot you in the face. Idiot move dipshit.")
        elif choice == "ceiling":
            print("You escaped! Now wash that money and don't go to prison.")
            escaped_cops = True

def dead(why):
    print(why)
    exit(0)

bank_vault()
escape_route()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function `escape_route` rather than exit.

Also, when checking for choice you call `dead` no matter what.

In reply to your comment:

You need to check if it's 0 then call `dead`, if it's not 0 don't bother with the else, go directly to the `if how_much < 5000000` and call `escape_route`

You need to try and convert the input to an `int` if it isn't 0!

And what happens if they take more than 5 mil?

Comment: Yeah I was just gonna say that, what do I do with that? I know thats a stupid question but Im a noob with python.

Comment: I took out the else but the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: Check the indentation of your `bank_vault` function. I would think that the `choice` and the `if` clauses should be part of that function too.

Comment: Last time I messed with the bank_vault it didn't run whatsoever and it didn't call any of the functions.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without seeing the code as is. Can you try and post it? (Edit your question)

Comment: It is badly formatted. This is how you had it in the first place. You have to make it look like it does for you with the proper indentation.

Comment: You need to convert your input to an int. It doesn't make sense only doing it if it's 0.

Comment: how_much = int(choice)

Comment: Yes but you do that within the scope of your first `if` so if it isn't 0 it doesn't get converted.

Comment: Nevermind the fact that you already call `exit` in the `dead` function meaning it will never be converted anyway.

Comment: Its in the same block. I don't understand what your trying to say. Should I move it directly under it?

Comment: Look at the indentation. In python indentation defines scope.

Comment: Okay, I put it right under the if. (Indentation wise) It still does it though.

Comment: If it is indented with respect to the `if` it belongs to that `if`. Remove the indentation.

Comment: I didn't want to fix it, I wanted you to learn to fix it yourself =) You should accept his answer.